# 4k Video rendering on Android TV Box (Mi Box)

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing a native Android app which has to be capable of playing native 4k video resolutions. In some parts of the app in a playlist on a VideoView and in some parts inside of a webview.

The views are all complete and functional, **but I am not able** to playback any video **above 1080p** resolution, it just does not load up.

I'm using the Android MediaPlayer class to stream videos from a local server, but I have not find any kind of settings to "unlock" higher resolutions.

**My setup:**

A 4k TV and a Mi Box (Android 6+), which is set on 4k resolution output, and a server in the local network where all the video files are streamed from.

I get following console outputs warning from the MediaPlayer on a video with higher resolution than 1080p:

```
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (8001, 0)
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (8004, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, 0)
D/Error:: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

Maybe someone of you can push me in the right direction?

**EDIT1:** The warning of 8004 seems to appear also on 1080p resolutions, so the warning code 8001 seems to be the more interesting ones. I was only able to find the description of a warning 801 here: "MEDIA_INFO_NOT_SEEKABLE" [MediaServer description](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java)

Comment: tried [exoplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)? `"ExoPlayer’s standard audio and video components are built on Android’s MediaCodec API, which was released in Android 4.1 (API level 16). Because ExoPlayer is a library, you can easily take advantage of new features as they become available by updating your app."`, some TV samples: https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback

Comment: Sorry wasn't able do test it out. To many projects simultaneously. But thanks for the tip and I'll look into it.